# How to pass out additional values with table in ref_cursor

Tags: plsql

I want to output an additional variable that's not in my table, can someone explain how to do this, or why it's not possible?

ie -

```
    OPEN V_CURSOR FOR SELECT ee.EmployeeID, v_overtime_worked FROM  EMPLOYEE_RECORDS ee;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to store in that cursor, data from the table, and another variable v_overtime_worked, that has nothing to do with the table?

What error are you receiving?

What I know for sure is that this is working...so basically you can put another variable in the cursor:

```
declare
c_Curs SYS_REFCURSOR;
v_overtime_worked VARCHAR2(120) := '1000';
v_book_title VARCHAR2(255) := '';
v_xxx         VARCHAR2(120);

BEGIN

 OPEN c_Curs FOR SELECT book_title, v_overtime_worked FROM  books;

 LOOP

 FETCH c_Curs INTO v_book_title, v_xxx;
 EXIT WHEN c_Curs%NOTFOUND OR c_Curs IS NULL;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_book_title || v_xxx);

 end loop;
 close c_Curs;

END;
```

As for your Java problem I'm afraid I don't know the answer..and i would need to do research :)

Maybe you need something like this :

```
@Override
                public void execute(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                    CallableStatement call = con.prepareCall(ProcedureCalls.GET_ALL_BOOKS);
                    call.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
                    call.execute(); 
                    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) call.getObject(1);
                    if(rs!=null){
                        while (rs.next ()) {
                            Book b = new Book();                                    
                            b.setBookId(rs.getLong("book_id"));
                            b.setBookTitle(rs.getString("title"));
                            b.setBookYear(rs.getInt("book_year"));
                            b.setBookAuthor(rs.getString("author"));
                            book_list.add(b);
                        }
                        if(rs!=null) rs.close();
                        if(call!= null) call.close();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Dim Employees As DataTable  = New GetEmployees(ot).Tables(0)

Comment: Sorry, my issue actually with calling the ref_cursor, I load it into a dataset
  `Dim Employees As DataTable  = New GetEmployees.Tables(0)`

Then I do a check for the new variable, but it cries that it's not part of the selected table. 
    `Employees.DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("v_overtime_worked")`

Comment: I don't understand what is the relation between that code that you just wrote, and the initial question...EDIT : ok now I see the problem

Comment: I'm in VB, I just meant that it doesn't return OVERTIME_WORKED, just EMPLOYEE_ID, even if I call the SP from within SQL Developer.

Comment: so you have a stored procedure, that returns the above mentioned cursor...have you tried my example ?...that one works as i tested it..Maybe you can paste the entire stored procedure, and how you use data from the cursor...That would be helpful

Comment: Tried that, seems the issue was with the naming of overtime, I just have it as v_overtime_worked as v_overtime_worked, and it now works. Before it'd come back as :B1